# Draw line equal to page width in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am using `Line` to draw line in my wp8 app, but when I change the page orientation, It's always the same width. I know the line width is static set to 480, how can I make it Auto to fit the page in both orientations. I'm using the line inside `ListBox` ItemTemplate.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lsbReadingChapter" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}" 
         Grid.Row="1" DoubleTap="lsbReadingChapter_DoubleTap">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          ....
          <Line X1="0" X2="480" Y1="0" Y2="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="LightGray" />
        </DataTemplate>

    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

How to draw the line to auto fit the page in both orientations?

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836595/display-a-line-after-a-textblock-in-silverlight? Set X2="1" and Stretch="Fill"?

Comment: Just curious, wouldn't Line Width="Auto" work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawing the lines, use border of height of 1 pt and width of 'auto'. Then you can set the `HorizontalAlignment` to stretch.

```
<Border Background="White" Height="1" Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

Comment: Though solution from @samjudson works, I checked `Border` as well but this didn't work.